# How to see inside a PHP object

Tags: php

I am working with a 3-rd party library and it makes some random call like this:

```
$consumer = getConsumer();
```

And I don't know what are the values inside the $consumer variable
I tried to do something like this:

```
echo '<p>consumer: '.$consumer.'</p>';
```

but that just crashed the page :) What is the real way for me to see what objects and values are in this $consumer object? And whats the best way to extract them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `var_dump($consumer);` or `print_r($consumer);`.

If it's an object, you access its parameters like so:

```
$consumer->parameter
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you do somehow manage to get access to the object (class) itself [**Reflection API**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) is an invaluable resource when it comes to dissecting objects in PHP > 5.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

```
$consumer = getConsumer();
var_dump($consumer); // no echo required
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty rusty on my PHP, but you might want to have a look at var_dump as well:

```
$consumer = getConsumer();
var_dump($consumer);
```

More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php